# How do I use data and conditions for Select Case in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically what I am trying to do:

```
Select Case test_expression
   Case condition_1
      result_1   
   Case condition_n
      result_n
End Select
```

I need that `condition_n`, `result_n` are read from a spreadsheet where `condition_1` and `result_1` are in columns A and B. Then rows will be added sometimes to the spreadsheet!

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: It isn't clear :) What rows will be added (inserted?), with what information, from where?

Comment: Could you provide us with a more complete extract from your code and a small example set from the columns A:B? Also please provide the additional information as requested by brettdj.

Comment: Seems more like a case for using vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to accomplish, but here is a try

```
Select Case test_expression 
    Case Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value 
        Dim s as String
        resultText = Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value

        'Now do something with resultText

    Case condition_n 
         result_n 
End Select
```

Comment: Ahmad - if you are *"Not sure what you want to accomplish"* how can you post an answer?